# Definition of Integral Domain: What does 'Ring with 1-element' mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

There are some definitions of an Integral Domain, that sound like

> An integral domain is a non-zero commutative ring with a '1'-element and without any zero divisors

So what does this "ring with a 1-element" mean? As far as I understand, the multiplication of each ring together with its elements form a monoid (otherwise it wouldn't be a ring), and so each ring as a '1'.

Comment: A ring may not have a multiplicative identity! See for example $2\mathbb{Z}$, it's a ring and the multiplication doesn't turn this set into a monoid! (it's a semigroup in general)

Comment: It means there is a unit element for multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is disagreement on the definition of "ring".  Some authors require it to be a monoid under multiplication, others do not.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Notes_on_the_definition).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a ring as having a multiplicative identity is not standard. Some authors don't require one.